How to make GROUP BY force to use index?
I have the following query:
SELECT user_id,
       type,
       cast(created_at as date) AS created_at,
       sum(credit) AS credit
FROM wallets_transactions
GROUP BY user_id, type, cast(created_at as date)

It takes about 7 secs to get executed:

Also, I have this index:
wallets_transactions(user_id, type, created_at)

And there is the result of EXPLAIN:

It looks like a full-scan. Any idea how can I make it more optimal?

Did you try to group without the cast? cast(created_at as date) I'm curious about it. Also, try to create an index with all 4 fields (also credit) Maybe it takes data from index instead to go to table.

@daniherrera Yeah, without casting it got much faster, less than 1 sec

What is created_at datatype? Provide complete CREATE TABLE script..

@Akina timestamp

Test CREATE INDEX idx ON wallets_transactions (user_id, type, (CAST(created_at AS DATE)), credit);

@Akina, I just tested that adding credit field to index don't avoid accessing credit field on table instead of index. Looks a bit weird, it is not? (What works effectively is including  (CAST(created_at AS DATE)) to index, thanks about the comment that should be the accepted answer)

@daniherrera You look for a plan on an empty table? of course you may see strange result...

@Akina, just tested with one million rows and also access to table instead to get all data from index.

cast(created_at as date) is not sargable .
If created_at is a VARCHAR, that is naughty.  Change it to DATETIME  There is no problem in comparing a DATETIME to a DATE, so don't worry about that.
Then INDEX(user_id, type, created_at, credit) would be optimal and "covering"

Thanks to illustrate us with "sargable" concept. You should also include type field in your index. Any case, change property type is not needed, you can create an index with (CAST(created_at AS DATE)) that optimizes query, see Akina's comment. Please, let me see that I'm wrong or fix the answer.

Being able to have CAST (etc) in an INDEX is a relatively new feature in MySQL  Since I don't know what version you (and other readers) are using, I suggested a better-in-the-long run answer.
